# Wordpress body class for Nextgen gallery

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

Design requires body background to be changed depending on Ngg gallery view or album view. How do I add body class 'gallery' when a gallery is displayed? I'm using one big album added to a page by shortcode with lots of galleries inside. This page has a special page_template. Also I created my own templates for gallery view and album view in templates folder. The only thing left is to add body class somehow.

upd: I'm using body_class() in body tag, need to add extra class when any gallery is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

add gallery as a page title to your page title by going to your single.php or page.php and change

```
<body>
```

in to

```
<body class="<?php the_title)(); ?>">
```

Anyways when you use this you can just style it trough CSS with the page title

Comment: the_title won't work. I'm using <body <?php body_class(); ?>> Need to add an extra class for gallery view to body classes.